# C++: Get data from MIDI message (DWORD)

Tags: c++, midi

I've written a simple MIDI console application in C++. Here's the whole thing:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
void CALLBACK midiInputCallback(HMIDIIN hMidiIn, UINT wMsg, DWORD_PTR dwInstance, DWORD_PTR dwParam1, DWORD_PTR dwParam2) {
 switch (wMsg) {
  case MIM_MOREDATA:
  case MIM_DATA:
   cout << dwParam1 << " ";
   PlaySound("jingle.wav", NULL, SND_ASYNC | SND_FILENAME);
   break;
 }
}
int main() {
 unsigned int numDevs = midiInGetNumDevs();
 cout << numDevs << " MIDI devices connected:" << endl;
 MIDIINCAPS inputCapabilities;
 for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numDevs; i++) {
  midiInGetDevCaps(i, &inputCapabilities, sizeof(inputCapabilities));
  cout << "[" << i << "] " << inputCapabilities.szPname << endl;
 }
 int portID;
 cout << "Enter the port which you want to connect to: ";
 cin >> portID;
 cout << "Trying to connect with the device on port " << portID << "..." << endl;
 LPHMIDIIN device = new HMIDIIN[numDevs];
 int flag = midiInOpen(&device[portID], portID, (DWORD)&midiInputCallback, 0, CALLBACK_FUNCTION);
 if (flag != MMSYSERR_NOERROR) {
  cout << "Error opening MIDI port." << endl;
  return 1;
 } else {
  cout << "You are now connected to port " << portID << "!" << endl;
  midiInStart(device[portID]);
 }
 while (1) {}
}
```

You can see that there's a callback function for handling the incoming MIDI messages from the device. [Here is the description of this function on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd798460(VS.85).aspx). On that page they say that the meaning of `dwParam1` and `dwParam2` are specified to the messagetype (`wMsg`), like `MIM_DATA`.

If I look up the documentation of [`MIM_DATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757284(VS.85).aspx), I can see that it is a doubleword (`DWORD`?) and that it has a 'high word' and a 'low word'. How can I now get data like the name of the control on the MIDI device that sended the data and what value it sends?

I would appreciate it if somebody can correct my code if it can be done better.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To access the data you need to use `dwParam1` and `dwParam2` and call the macros `HIWORD` and `LOWORD` to get the high and low word from them. Respectively use `HIBYTE` and `LOBYTE` to get the data out of those words. In case of `MIM_DATA`, unfortunately that's byte encoded MIDI data, so you'll have to find the specific meanings for those -- these are documented here -- [MIDI Messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd798498(VS.85).aspx).

Your code however has a potential problem -- as we read in the MSDN pages:

> "Applications should not call any
>   multimedia functions from inside the
>   callback function, as doing so can
>   cause a deadlock. Other system
>   functions can safely be called from
>   the callback".

And you're calling PlaySound in the Callback...

Comment: That's really cool. :) It works, didn't think it would be that simple!
And thanks for giving such a quick and helpful reply.

Comment: Thanks for your note about `PlaySound`. It was just a tryout to use that function there so I can still change that.